# Is there any guides on how to use T4 to generate aspx or ascx?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, code-generation, t4

I have a task to generate user controls, I'm wondering if there's any guides on that.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first ask why you need to "generate" user controls. If you need a lot of very similar controls for some reason, couldn't you create one user control that adjusts itself depending on some kind of input parameter?

Assuming that you have a good reason for doing this, though, I can offer the following general T4 advice. Start by writing an example of what you want to generate. Create an actual control like the one you want to generate. If possible, do this as a single file (classic asp style), it will be easier to generate the control as one file than multiples which then have to be associated together inside the project file... very messy. Change the file's extension to .tt, and start factoring out the parts of the example control that need to change form one generated control to the next. Try altering one aspect of the control at a time, generating the output, and comparing against what you expected. Keep changing one thing at a time until the control you started with has become a template to *generate* controls like the one you started with.

T4 templates only know how to write out a single file. Since you want to create multiple controls, you'll need some extra tools. The T4 Toolbox has what you need to accomplish this, as described [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/).

Comment: no, parameter thing isn't effective for us, we're doing this to save developers time, and give them full control at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: The answer is for our experience and for a technology that is published and completely open to use. Based on standards, this is not a product "sell", answers exactly to the question.

We have gotten great experience in both productivity and trivialization aspects (for fields unknown to end-developers) in an XML schema and XML controlled T4 generation.

The idea is that the architect in charge will constrain the development by logical architectural limits.

We have published the technology as completely open; the basic idea is to distribute the entire folder with the schema and the T4 generator(s) to each individual project in fully open source form.

In internal development you can version control branching and merging to update the changes to the templates/abstractions of the controls, so that you can build single distribution.

The very nature of the technology is that the end-developers can customize every aspect they need to by adjusting the generator(s), the schema and the xml contents as appropriate.

And the time return-of-investment is basically negative compared to traditional guidance; you also gain the strict control over the code produced.

You can check out the videos for the way of doing; the example demonstrates trivializing PowerPoint add-in, but the technology is completely open, completely target-platform agnostic.

http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=B3366B17004D5DB9

More info and updates are posted through the blog:

http://abstractiondev.wordpress.com

I'm adding more explaining videos for creating abstractions from scratch. The HelloWorld in its bare simplicity works for focused sample in case either Office/COM Add-In (and its complexity) or CQRS stack is not familiar to you

Comment: I'm adding more explaining videos for creating abstractions from scratch. The HelloWorld in its bare simplicity works for focused sample in case either Office/COM Add-In (and its complexity) or CQRS stack is not familiar to you.